# Reading file path from user in simple format "c:\files\sample.txt"

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read file path from user as command line in simple format
ex:

```
path="c:\files\sample.txt"
```

but when trying to access using `file.open("c:\files\sample.txt");`
file not found.

so i used `path.replace(path.begin(),path.end(),"\\","\\\\")` for it to change `\ to \\` but its not working.

Help me!!

Comment: A single '\' in a string is an escape character, but not a "\" , the real string of the path is `"c:(\f)iles(\s)ample.txt"`, so the replace function will not find  the "\".

Comment: Instead of `path.replace`, why not initialize `path` as `C:\\files\\sample.txt` ?

Comment: end user is not aware about computer field they can just copy the file path and paste so it could create problems further.

Comment: You don't need to double up on backslashes in runtime data, only in compile-time literals.

Comment: To be not confused with char escaping use the special form of defining string liberals that disables char escaping: `file.open(R"(c:\files\sample.txt)");`

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know

```
path="c:\files\sample.txt";
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
path="c:\\files\\sample.txt";
```

(or forward slashes work as well)

```
path="c:/files/sample.txt";
```

But this is also incorrect

```
path="c:\files\sample.txt";
path.replace(path.begin(),path.end(),"\\","\\\\");
```

The second line replaces all the single backslashes with double backslashes, **but** there are no single backslashes in your original string.

`\f` is an *escape sequence* for the *form feed* character, and `\s` not even a legal character sequence.

Escape sequences are used in string literals to denote characters which would otherwise be hard to write. For instance you cannot easily put `"` in a string literal because it would end the string, so the escape sequence `\"` exists to let you do this. Similarly since the backslash character is used to start an escape sequence,  the escape sequence `\\` stands for the backslash character itself.

These rules apply to string literals only, if you are reading a string from the user then there is no need to replace the backslashes with double backslashes, that makes no sense because single backslashes are what you want in a file path. It's just that the way to get single backslashes in a string literal is to write double backslashes.